# How to delete files from a directory that exit in a tar file using ant

Tags: ant

In a primitive sense I'm looking for the ant pronunciation of

```
tar -tzf <tarfile> | grep '<regex>' | xargs rm
```

That's oversimplified.  I'm writing a clean target.  I want to delete headers from an include directory if a header with the same name exists in a tar file they came from.

A more complex example of what I'd like to say is

```
tar --transform 's|^.*/([^/]+)$|\1|x' \
    --show-transformed-names          \
    -tzf $ARCHIVE | grep '.*\.h$' |   \ 
    ( cd $TARGET/include && xargs -d'\n' rm -f )
```

Comment: Have you looked at [delete task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html)?

Comment: Yes.  I wasn't sure how to get the list of paths from the tar archive in a form that I could filter and pass to <delete>.  After a good bit of reading on filesets, resources and the like, the best I could tell is I need a selector like <present> that is tarfile aware.  I found examples for removing files in a matching path existed in another directory.  Just not in a tar file.